# How to make tooltip background transparent?

Tags: osx, faces, colors, tooltip

I want to make the tooltip background somewhat transparent, say, change it `alpha` value to `0.5`.

I find these code in `tooltip.el.gz`

```
(defface tooltip
  '((((class color))
     :background "lightyellow"
     :foreground "black"
     :inherit variable-pitch)
    (t
     :inherit variable-pitch))
  "Face for tooltips."
  :group 'tooltip
  :group 'basic-faces)
```

There is a `:background` property, so my question is:

1. How to change this value in my `init.el` so that I do not change the origin file.
2. How to make it transparent?

Thanks!

Comment: the configuration in the local configuration file will override the default. also look in https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Faces.html#Faces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Customize option `tooltip-frame-parameters`, specifying an `alpha` parameter value that is less than 100.

See the Elisp manual, node [Font and Color Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Font-and-Color-Parameters.html), for information about parameter `alpha`. There, you see this:

> This parameter specifies the opacity of the frame, on graphical
>        displays that support variable opacity.  It should be an integer
>        between 0 and 100, where 0 means completely transparent and 100
>        means completely opaque.  It can also have a `nil` value, which
>        tells Emacs not to set the frame opacity (leaving it to the window
>        manager).
>
> To prevent the frame from disappearing completely from view, the
>        variable `frame-alpha-lower-limit` defines a lower opacity limit.
>        If the value of the frame parameter is less than the value of this
>        variable, Emacs uses the latter.  By default,
>        `frame-alpha-lower-limit` is 20.
>
> The `alpha` frame parameter can also be a cons cell `(ACTIVE . INACTIVE)`, where `ACTIVE` is the opacity of the frame when it is
>        selected, and `INACTIVE` is the opacity when it is not selected.
>
> Some window systems do not support the `alpha` parameter for child
>        frames (see Child Frames).

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify which platform you're on, but under X11 you can do something like

```
(setq x-gtk-use-system-tooltips nil)
(setf (alist-get 'alpha tooltip-frame-parameters) 0.5)
```

The first line is needed because otherwise emacs will use GTK tooltips, which don't respect the tooltip frame parameters. There does seem to be some support in GTK for changing the alpha of the tooltip frame via a theme.

Comment: How to do this on mac?

Comment: No idea, I don't have one.